# How to disable auto completion pop up in idea

Tags: intellij-idea

Recently the code completion popup inside IDEA is getting on my nerves. It is extremely useful when I invoke it with alt+space but the auto popup is totally in my way, when I am trying to type. Is there a way to disable it and tell IDEA to only provide this on ALT+SPACE?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`File` -> `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Code completion`

Uncheck *Autopoup code completion in (ms)*. Works for me on 10.5.